# nvim mason python plugin not able to create venv

Tags: python, plugins, neovim, python-venv

Im actauly working some plugin with nvim: debugpy,ruff,black,mypy

and some plugin themself cannot create a venv. So i tried doing it myself

`python3 -m venv venv`

but error shows up. Please help

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\opt\lib\python3.9\runpy.py", line 210, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\opt\lib\python3.9\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\opt\lib\python3.9\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvm4homz5\pip-21.2.4-py3-none-any.whl\pip\__main__.py", line 31, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvm4homz5\pip-21.2.4-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 55, in main
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvm4homz5\pip-21.2.4-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 58, in parse_command
  File "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\opt\lib\python3.9\optparse.py", line 1371, in parse_args
    values = self.get_default_values()
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvm4homz5\pip-21.2.4-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\cli\parser.py", line 277, in get_default_values
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvm4homz5\pip-21.2.4-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 134, in load
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvm4homz5\pip-21.2.4-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 256, in _load_config_files
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvm4homz5\pip-21.2.4-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 359, in iter_config_files
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvm4homz5\pip-21.2.4-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 75, in get_configuration_files
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvm4homz5\pip-21.2.4-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\utils\appdirs.py", line 31, in site_config_dirs
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvm4homz5\pip-21.2.4-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 243, in site_config_dir
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvm4homz5\pip-21.2.4-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 138, in site_data_dir
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvm4homz5\pip-21.2.4-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 486, in _get_win_folder_from_registry
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\opt\lib\python3.9\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\opt\lib\python3.9\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\opt\lib\python3.9\ensurepip\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(ensurepip._main())
  File "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\opt\lib\python3.9\ensurepip\__init__.py", line 206, in _main
    return _bootstrap(
  File "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\opt\lib\python3.9\ensurepip\__init__.py", line 125, in _bootstrap
    return _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
  File "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\opt\lib\python3.9\ensurepip\__init__.py", line 34, in _run_pip
    return subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-c", code], check=True).returncode
  File "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\opt\lib\python3.9\subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Users\\Administrator\\venv\\bin\\python3.exe', '-c', '\nimport runpy\nimport sys\nsys.path = [\'C:\\\\Users\\\\ADMINI~1\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\tmpvm4homz5\\\\setuptools-58.1.0-py3-none-any.whl\', \'C:\\\\Users\\\\ADMINI~1\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\tmpvm4homz5\\\\pip-21.2.4-py3-none-any.whl\'] + sys.path\nsys.argv[1:] = [\'install\', \'--no-cache-dir\', \'--no-index\', \'--find-links\', \'C:\\\\Users\\\\ADMINI~1\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\tmpvm4homz5\', \'--upgrade\', \'setuptools\', \'pip\']\nrunpy.run_module("pip", run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)\n']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Error: Command '['C:\\Users\\Administrator\\venv\\bin\\python3.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

And this is my path if u want to know

[image]

And this is what i installed with chocolatey

[image]

Comment: Just a guess, you seem to have installed multiple python environment on your computer. Your PATH environment variables might be messed up.

Comment: im sure i dont have any environment in my path, or can u give me example for a enviroment path

Comment: (1) In your trace back message, there is `"C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\opt\lib\python3.9\runpy.py"`, and I guess there is one python installed using chocolatey, is it right? (2) In your image of `PATH`, the first one is `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python`, and I think this is another python. So I conclude that you have multiple python installed. And this seems to affect the execution of `python3 -m venv venv`.

Comment: i have already check what i have installed with chocolatey, didn't see python being installed with chocolatey

Comment: Oh, then I guess mingw in chocolatey has some python code. I am not clear how to fix this.

Comment: i found the issue, there is somehow a python terminal after i delete python fully. It was in a chocolatey file. After deleting and and download python from official page it was working again